# Header is flickering on live site

Tags: html, css, frontend

when hovering just bellow the nav items (* apart from the first one), the indicator just starts flickering back and forth and bugs out!

it is worth mentioning that the site that the actual code is one is A WordPress site and the language is Hebrew so it is right to left, not sure if that changes anything...

CODEPEN: [Nav menu link](https://codepen.io/Jordan-goren/pen/GRPJLde)

raw html and css:

```css
nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav a {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Assistant;
  font-weight: light;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  transition: 0.4s ease color;
}

nav a:before,
nav a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.5s ease transform;
}

nav a:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 37%;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}

nav a:after {
  top: 5px;
  left: calc(37% + 12px);
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
}

nav a:nth-child(1):before {
  background-color: rgb(255, 199, 44);
}

nav a:nth-child(1):after {
  background-color: rgb(216, 215, 195);
}

nav a:nth-child(2):before {
  background-color: rgb(216, 215, 195);
}

nav a:nth-child(2):after {
  background-color: rgb(125, 185, 179);
}

nav a:nth-child(3):before {
  background-color: rgb(125, 185, 179);
}

nav a:nth-child(3):after {
  background-color: rgb(22, 102, 120);
}

nav a:nth-child(4):before {
  background-color: rgb(22, 102, 120);
}

nav a:nth-child(4):after {
  background-color: rgb(14, 46, 59);
}

#indicator {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.15s ease right;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #0e2e3b;
}

nav a:hover:before,
nav a:hover:after {
  transform: scale(1);
}

nav a:nth-child(1):hover~#indicator {
  right: 85%;
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, rgb(255, 199, 44), rgb(216, 215, 195));
}

nav a:nth-child(2):hover~#indicator {
  right: 60%;
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, rgb(216, 215, 195), rgb(125, 185, 179));
}

nav a:nth-child(3):hover~#indicator {
  right: 35%;
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, rgb(125, 185, 179), rgb(22, 102, 120));
}

nav a:nth-child(4):hover~#indicator {
  right: 10%;
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, rgb(22, 102, 120), rgb(14, 46, 59));
}
```

```html
<nav lang="he">
  <a href="#about">about</a>
  <a href="#method">the method</a>
  <a href="#twitter">blog</a>
  <a href="yairgoren.com/en">English</a>
  <div id="indicator"></div>
</nav>
```

trying some CSS tricks with hiding the indicator while hovering on it, didn't work...

Comment: You don't have to use codepen. Use the `<>` button to create a runnable snippet. It will be executable directly on StackOverflow and people can copy it to the answer to help more quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying

```css
#indicator {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

...fixes the issue.

When you hover a link, the indicator moves below it and gets hovered itself. At which point the link is no longer hovered and the indicator moves back to its original position, which makes the link  get hovered again, into an endless cycle.

Therefore, making the indicator transparent to pointer events prevents the flickering behavior, because the indicator is no longer capable of stealing the `:hover` from the link when transitioning under the mouse position.

Comment: In principle, you should avoid formulating answers as *"Try `someCode`"* as they project uncertainty. The cause of the bug is exactly what you have mentioned and applying the suggestion fixes it in 100% of cases. Even if you want to be less assertive, you might want to formulate it as: "Applying `#indicator { pointer-events: none }` fixes the issue, because this and that...".